# Error "Call to a member function orderBy() on null"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using **PHP / Laravel**, but I got an error its about 3 days now I try to fix it by my self, but I couldn't.

**this is my code :**

```
public function getCollection()
    {
        $queryStrings = $this->getQueryStrings();

        if(count($queryStrings)){
            // dd($queryStrings);
            $filteredOrSorteredCollection = $this->sortOrFilterCollection(
                $this->queryBuilder,
                $queryStrings
            );

            return $this->collection = $this->generateResults($filteredOrSorteredCollection);
        }

        return $this->collection = $this->generateResults($this->queryBuilder);
    }

public function sortOrFilterCollection($collection, $parseInfo)
    {
        foreach($parseInfo as $key => $info){

            switch($key){
                case 'sort':
                    $this->sortCollection($collection, $info);
                    break;

                case 'search':
                    // dd($collection->toSql());
                    // dd($info);
                    $this->searchCollection($collection, $info);
                    break;

                    // need more here
            }
        }
    }

private function searchCollection($collection, $info)
    {
        $countKeys = count(array_keys($info));

        if($countKeys > 1){
            dd('error'.__METHOD__);
        }
        
        if($countKeys == 1){
            // dd(12);
            $collection->where(function($collection) use ($info) {

                foreach($this->columns as $column){

                    if(isset($column['searchable']) && $column['searchable'] == true){

                        $this->resolve($collection, $column['index'], 'like', '%' . $info['all'] . '%', 'orWhere');
                    }

                }

            });
        }

    }

private function resolve($collection, $columnName, $condition, $filterValue, $clause = 'where', $method = 'resolveQuery')
    {

        if($this->enableFilterMap && isset($this->filterMap[$columnName])){
            $this->$method($collection, $this->filterMap[$columnName], $condition, $filterValue, $clause);
            // dd('block 1');
        } else if ($this->enableFilterMap && !isset($this->filterMap[$columnName])){
            // dd('block 2');
            $this->$method($collection, $columnName, $condition, $filterValue, $clause);

        } else {
            dd('block 3');
            $this->$method($collection, $columnName, $condition, $filterValue, $clause);
        }
    }

private function resolveQuery($query, $columnName, $condition, $filterValue, $clause = 'where')
    {
        if($clause === 'whereBetween'){
            return $query->$clause($columnName, $filterValue);
        } else {
            return $query->$clause($columnName, $this->operators[$condition], $filterValue);
        }
    }

public function generateResults($queryBuilderOrCollection)
    {
        // dd($queryBuilderOrCollection);
        if($this->paginate){
            if($this->itemsPerPage > 0){
                // dd(5);
                return $this->paginateResults($queryBuilderOrCollection);
            }
        }else{
            return $this->defaultResults($queryBuilderOrCollection);
        }
    }
```

**I tried to debug so many times using dd to trace each variable from the to the end,**

By the way resovleQuery (else part ) works really fine and, I get the database result I checked using `dd`.

**Result is always :**

```
Call to a member function orderBy() on null

    private function paginateResults($queryBuilderOrCollection){
        // dd($queryBuilderOrCollection);
        return $this->collection = $queryBuilderOrCollection->orderBy($this->index, $this->sortOrder)->paginate($this->itemsPerPage);
    }
```

Comment: You're not showing where `paginateResults` results is called, so there's pretty much no way to know what is causing the error. Find where `paginateResults` is called and figure out why something is passing `null` as the argument.

Comment: @404NotFound  can you double check please Code updated ( generateResults function )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: On second review, try my second suggestion after my "However" below, then try the first one if that doesn't work.

In `getCollection()` you're passing the result of `sortOrFilterCollection()` to `generateResults()`, which calls `paginateResults()` where the error occurs.

```php
$filteredOrSorteredCollection = $this->sortOrFilterCollection(
    $this->queryBuilder,
    $queryStrings
);

return $this->collection = $this->generateResults($filteredOrSorteredCollection);
```

However, `sortOrFilterCollection()` **does not return anything**, so `$filteredOrSorteredCollection` will be `null`. (Side note: You've got a typo with "Sortered", you probably want to change it to "Sorted".) I think you need to change `sortOrFilterCollection()` to return the results of the functions it's calling, which also means you can remove the `break` statements, like this:

```php
public function sortOrFilterCollection($collection, $parseInfo)
{
    foreach($parseInfo as $key => $info){

        switch($key){
            case 'sort':
                return this->sortCollection($collection, $info);

            case 'search':
                // dd($collection->toSql());
                // dd($info);
                return $this->searchCollection($collection, $info);

                 // need more here
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, you're also not returning anything from `searchCollection` or `resolve`.

So, *on second thought*, your code might be designed to be working by modifying the `$queryBuilder` reference. In that case, you might actually need to change the `getCollection()` lines to this:

```php
// Modify `$this->queryBuilder` object
$this->sortOrFilterCollection(
    $this->queryBuilder,
    $queryStrings
);

return $this->collection = $this->generateResults($this->queryBuilder);
```

I'm not sure how your code is designed to work, so either you need to add `return` statements to several other functions, or you shouldn't expect return values and you need to pass the `queryBuilder` around.

Comment: Thank you so much i tried the second solution by using $this->queryBuilder as a parameter value.